# How to turn off showing assembly codes when debug?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, assembly

I accidentially turn on this mode and want to return to previous setting. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about VS2010, but in VS 2008 Go to Tools->Options->Debugging->General and uncheck Show disassembly if source is not available.

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Options->Debugging->General-> Uncheck "Enable address-level debugging->Show disassembly if source not available"

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

All debugging options are in the Debug menu => Option & Settings. Could you explain your issue a little more precisely?

Either way, look at the different options available here, in the Debugging tab.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can turn it off in the same way that you turned it on:

On the **Debug** menu, choose **Windows**, and click **Disassembly**.